# Ошибка: NullPointerException: 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Ошибка при компиляции... Кто знает в чем проблема?

```
public class CurrentTaskFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView rvCurrentTask;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private CurrentTasksAdapter adapter;

public CurrentTaskFragment() {

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_current_task, container, false);

    rvCurrentTask = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.rvCurrentTasks);

    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rvCurrentTask.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    adapter = new CurrentTasksAdapter();
    rvCurrentTask.setAdapter(adapter);

    return rootView;
}
```

**Лог:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main   
Process: devferrarizero.whattodotasklist, PID: 2621
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
at devferrarizero.whattodotasklist.fragment.DoneTaskFragment.onCreateView(DoneTaskFragment.java:33)
```

Comment: rvCurrentTask у вас null. Скорее всего вы просто опечатались и ошиблись в id или рагрузили не ту разметку во фрагмент.

Comment: Уже несколько раз перепроверил.... вроде все нормально загрузил....

Comment: В приведённом вами коде ошибок нет. У вас 99% где-то опечатка.